# Compile Error 'cannot convert' on Declared Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, func

I'm having issues when passing a delegate as a Where parameter in LINQ.

I'm declaring a delegate in the namespace:

`public delegate bool FilterInt<in T>(T x);`

I've made a method to assign to the delegate and then assign it:

```
    public static bool FilterData(int val)
    {
        if (val < 10)
            return true;
        return false;

    }
```

When I try to filter a List using the delegate I get a compile time error 'Cannot conver from FilterInt to Func<Int, bool>:

```
listInt.Where(_filterer);
```

However, I can use the below (an implied delegate?) without any issues:

```
listInt.Where(FilterData);
```

I have the same issue with _comparer when I follow the MSDN doc on delegates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/delegate-class) if I define my own delegate in the namespace as per the below:

```
public delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y);

public static int CompareLength(string left, string right) =>
     right.Length.CompareTo(left.Length);

readonly Comparison<string> _comparer = CompareLength;

list.Sort(_comparer);
```

However, if I omit the initial declaration of Comparison, it works fine (note - Comparison exists in the System namespace).

I assume it's an issue with my initial delegate declaration.

Comment: What's the type of `_filterer`?

Comment: You can use like this .Where(x => FilterInt(x))

Comment: _filterer is of type FilterInt<int>. I know there are ways around the issue but i'm trying to figure out why this method in particular isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) accepts `Func<TSource, bool>` delegate. If you look for documentation on [`Func<T,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1) you will find out that it is declared as:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
```

So you will need to "convert" your delegate into instance of `Func<TSource, bool>` which is possible either with direct creation an instance of the delegate:

```
new[] { 1 }.Where(new Func<int, bool>(_filterer));
```

Or with anonymous (lambda) function:

```
new[] { 1 }.Where(i => _filterer(i));
```

Which is actually a syntactic sugar [transformed by compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjgNyEYDM5WpAwqQN6FSw8pwwpSAWQAUASgGEAkCNIAxWgBsALjCgBJeloA8DLQD5SAfQBmmnbCikAvGru6AIgEMtn1gWUi9DAA7gDaALoCpDikAL6UAOoAFrow0rTOFjZuDumysn4qsUIiJcIcpAAmMBowAObeMKTAEBAartq6BsYMpAAqZtJ9pAgFhGxiOEjNre3qnVBePumGpABunhqyhIL+tNak0hvtRtHE2/6KGADspFpQAK4wfle31psAzs/jBMW/QA=) into something like this:

```
 // generated class to hold your lambda:
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public FilterInt<int> _filterer;
    // your lambda: 
    internal bool <M>b__0(int i)
    {
        return _filterer(i);
    }
}

   
// instantiation of new Func<int, bool>
Enumerable.Where(array, new Func<int, bool>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>b__0));
```

Method group call (`listInt.Where(FilterData);`) also is syntactic sugar [expanded by compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjgNyEYDM5WpAwqQN6FSw8pwwpSAWQAUASgGEAkCNIAxWgBsALjCgBJeloA8DLQD5SAfQBmmnbCikAvGru6AIgEMtn1gWUi9DAA7gDaALoCpDikAL6UAOoAFrow0uraHt6esn4qsUIihcIcpAAmMBowAObeMKTAEBAarpn6hib0pAAqZtLdpAi5hGxiOEgNTS0Z9l4+0qakAG6eGrKEgv601qTSKy1G0cTr/ooYAOykWlAArjB+Z5fWqwDO9yMEBZ9AA==) into creation of new delegate:

```
Enumerable.Where(array, new Func<int, bool>(FilterData));
```

Comment: This makes sense! What i'm still not understanding though is why I can do is why a very similar version of this using Comparison<string> _comparer = CompareLength; and list.Sort(_comparer); does work? It's exactly the same apart from that Comparison<string> is a type already declared in .NET. What makes less sense again is that if I override the declaration of the Comparison<in T> delegate in the namespace with exactly the same code as it is originally declared, list.Sort(_comparer) throws the same error as in my original question

Comment: This is exactly what i'm not grasping. I've updated the original post with more info on this side of it. Essentially, if I declare a public delegate named Comparison<T> and match it identically to the System name space declaration, my delegate field doesn't work. If I remove it and instead the delegate field looks at the System namespace declaration, it does work. It leads me to believe that what i'm doing in my original post should actually work and it's an issue with declaring the delegate in the current namespace (even though I know that doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @TomBennett you have defined your own delegate. It does not matter that it has the same name as built in one, they are different ones, and `Sort` expecting the build in one.

Comment: Explicitly stating that System.Comparison<string> _comparer = CompareLength allows _comparer to be passed into Sort but when I just say CurrentNamespace.Comparison<string> _comparer = CompareLength, _comparer is unable to be passed into Sort even though the declaration of System.Comparison and CurrentNamespace.Comparison are the same, just i've declared CurrentNamespace.Comparison myself inside my own namespace (again, I know I wouldn't need to do this, i'm just trying to figure out why I can't for my own educational purposes)

Comment: @TomBennett if you define some class with the same name and structure as a build in one, you will not be able to pass instance of it to method expecting instance of build in one. With delegates is the same, actually internally in [IL they are classes too](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs4foBMZcYAcwCGGGHWwA7DMwgBbAA7Co2AM4RJAHil0AKgD4AFLroI0eugE8AlAG4OXWgxR0AsoetsHnAL7fuDKRIEtKyisowADIwkoIYABaGhKQADHQCAGYY5slpKoLxGJ4AvPr+dPmFAHTRsQlVTPJKsLoQhpkYNTFx8XZUVLDCPBq4lmHNahqaufp0APqQ4bBQdMXjEbU99pQ+QA===).

Answer (score 1):

You can call like this.

```
Where(new Func<int, bool>(FilterInt))
```

Or

```
.Where(x => FilterInt(x))
```

Comment: That's great and these work. Is there any reason you can tell why my method does not work though? It's more for educational purposes that actual application.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because of the `where` clause expects a `Func<TSource, TResult>` with a Boolean as `TResult` and not just a `Func<int>` as its representative.

```
IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

The closest way to use it as you wish will be something like this, but I don't believe it as a good implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public delegate Func<T1, T2> FilterInt<in T1, out T2>(T1 value);

namespace DelegateTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly List<int> List = new List<int> {0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12};

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FilterInt<int, bool> filterInt = FilterData;
            var result = List.Where(x => filterInt.Invoke(x).Invoke(x));
            foreach (var item in result) Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }

        private static Func<int, bool> FilterData(int value) => _ => value < 10;
    }
}
```